# undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class, Partial views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial-views

I am using partial view that is not working,                                             in review#new action, I have a from and I am calling the post partial view :

```
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>

    <div>
    <%= field_with_error @review, :content do %>
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
    <% end -%>
    </div>

    <%= field_with_error @review, :score do %>
    <%= f.label :score %>
    <%= f.text_field :score %>
    <% end -%>

   <p><%= submit_tag 'Post Review'%> </p>
  <% end %>
     </div>

    <ul >
     <%= render :partial => "post", :locals => {:review =>  @reviews}  %>
   </ul>
```

in Review#new controller :

```
  def new
      @review = Review.new(:restaurant_id => params[:restaurant_id])   
      @reviews = Review.all
  end
```

and review#_post looks like:

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, review) do %>
  <p ><%= "#{review.first_name}" %></p>
  <p ><%= review.content %></p>
  <span >Posted at <%= review.created_at %> ago.
  (<%= link_to 'Delete', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %>)</span>
<% end %>
```

It gives an error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for Array:Class
```

I think I am doing sth wrong with the partial view, Thanks you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

In your view you have:

```
<ul >
  <%= render :partial => "post", :locals => {:review =>  @reviews}  %>
</ul>
```

You're passing `@reviews` here which is an array, not the model `@review`. Delete the `s` at the end of `@reviews` here and it should work. :)

EDIT: If you want to render a list of all the reviews in `@reviews`, you could do something like this:

```
<ul >
  <%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @reviews  %>
</ul>
```

Check the [documentation on partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) for more options on how to do this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply :), I try the second one with reviews, it still give me the same error:                                           undefined local variable or method `review' for #<#<Class:0x1324776c8>:0x13246f838>

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. From the documentation: "When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the collection being rendered *via a variable named after the partial*." So it's looking for a variable named `post` because your partial file is named '_post'. Can you change the filename to '_review'? That would make more sense anyway.